# How to distribute three kinds of things of $2n$ each equally in between two people?

Tags: combinatorics

I have been working on this problem from Arthur Engel's problem solving strategies and I need some help here.

Here is the question. $2n$ objects each of $3$ kinds are given to two people in such a way that each person gets $3n$ objects. Prove that this can be done in $3n^2 + 3n + 1$ ways.

I need help with two things. 
1. To sort out my approach. 
2. In understanding the enlightened approach of the book.

Here is my approach.

I noticed that this problem can be recast to be asking, how many ways can three numbers add up to give a sum of $3n$ with this constraint.

$$a + b + c = 3n$$ 
$$ 0 \leq a, b, c \leq 2n$$

I also noticed that for each way we give these objects ne person, there is only one corresponding way to give it to the other person. So, to count the number of ways the distribution can be done, it is sufficient to count the number of ways one person is given the objects. Here, is what I've done.

I fix the value of $a$, and then vary $b $and $c $.

$$ 
\begin{align}
0 &&+ n &&+ 2n \\ 
0 &&+ n+1&& + 2n-1 \\ 
\vdots \\
0 && + n + n && + 2n -n
\end{align}
$$

The $0$ can be placed in any box. So the total number of possibilities is $3\times(n+1)$.

$$ 
\begin{align}
1 &&+ n -1&&+ 2n \\ 
1 &&+ n&& + 2n-1 \\ 
\vdots \\
1 && + n + n && + 2n -(n+1)
\end{align}
$$

Similarly, the total number of ways this can be done is $3\times(n+2)$.

$\vdots$

$$ 
\begin{align}
n-1 &&+ 1 &&+ 2n \\ 
n-1&&+ 2&& + 2n-1\\ 
\vdots \\
n-1 && + 2n&& + 2n - (2n-1)
\end{align}
$$

The total number of ways is $3\times(2n)$.

After this we stop because if $a = n $, one of the other two become $0$ and this possibility is already counted.

So the total number of ways is...

$$3( n + 1 + n + 2 + \dots + n + n)$$ which is not the required answer.

Creative approach :

I didn't understand the creative approach at all. It made the enlightened observation that $3n^2 + 3n + 1 = (n+1)^3 - n^3$. A person gets $x+y+z = 3n$ objects with $0 \leq x, y, z \leq 2n$. These are triangular coordinates with altitude $3n$. $x, y, z$ can be interpreted as lattice points. The hexagon in the figure can be interpreted as the projection of the cube with edge $n+1$ from which a cube of edge $n$ is subtracted.

I don't understand this. What hexagon? How is it a triangle? I don't know anything about triangular coordinates. What do I need to learn to understand this ?

Comment: See also these two: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258694, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457921 (I'm not closing as a duplicate since you asked about particular approaches).

Comment: @joriki Good decision.

Comment: I suspect there is more connection between your approach and the "enlightened" one to be explained.  However the title for this Question could be more descriptive of your actual problem.  See if my edit helps.

Comment: @hardmath I don't see much connection to be honest. But, thanks for the edit. I'll make it more descriptive.

Comment: As a short note to see that your approach still has some overcounting, note that the last lines of your second (first column = $1$) and last lists (first column = $n-1$) are duplicative ($1+(n-1)+2n = 3n$).

Answer (score 1):

In your own approach, you're double-counting – this is most directly seen in the top rows of the second and third blocks, which both count the same possibilities.

In the "creative approach", "triangular coordinates" refers to [barycentric coordinates on triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles). If you normalise by $3n$, the constraints $x,y,z\le 2n$ correspond to $x,y,z\le\frac23$, three lines that cut a regular hexagon out of an equilateral triangle. Now imagine looking at the corner of a cube along the space diagonal through that corner. The projection of the three faces you see along your line of sight is a regular hexagon; removing an $n^3$ cube from an $(n+1)^3$ cube leaves those three faces, and you can map their lattice points to the lattice points in the hexagon cut out of the triangle.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by normalising in the triangular coordinates ? I take it you mean dividing by $3n$.